# Error when closing tkinter app with figure and canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar, figure

I get the following error when I resize the right expand the window and then close it:
*_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!scrollbar"*
Maybe it's related to the canvas widget.
I tried a lot, but without results.

can anyone help me?

The code is below

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root=tk.Tk()

vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root)

canvasF2= tk.Canvas(root,yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)

vscrollbar.config(command=canvasF2.yview)
vscrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y) 

frame2=tk.Frame(canvasF2) #Create the frame which will hold the widgets

canvasF2.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

##Updated the window creation
canvasF2.create_window(0,0,window=frame2, anchor='nw')
#
fig = Figure(figsize=(10, 4), dpi=100)
t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
a = fig.add_subplot(111)
a.plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, frame2)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nswe")

def on_configure(event):    
    canvasF2.configure(scrollregion=canvasF2.bbox('all'))

root.bind('<Configure>', on_configure) 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfect, clean and brilliant solution: it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this error triggers when the window is closed, my guess is somehow after closing the window the widget `canvasF2` is not getting destroyed properly. So if we destroy `canvasF2` properly before closing the window the error won't trigger. I think there'll be a better way of doing this but here's what I did.

I handled the [deletion of the window by using **protocol** method](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-window-destroy.htm). I added this to the end of your code and I got no error by destroying `canvasF2` before the main window is destroyed.

```py
def close_window():
    canvasF2.destroy()
    root.destroy()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_window)
```

---

**Complete Code:**

```py
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root=tk.Tk()

vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root)

canvasF2= tk.Canvas(root,yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)

vscrollbar.config(command=canvasF2.yview)
vscrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y) 

frame2=tk.Frame(canvasF2) #Create the frame which will hold the widgets

canvasF2.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

##Updated the window creation
canvasF2.create_window(0,0,window=frame2, anchor='nw')
#
fig = Figure(figsize=(10, 4), dpi=100)
t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
a = fig.add_subplot(111)
a.plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, frame2)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nswe")

def on_configure(event):    
    canvasF2.configure(scrollregion=canvasF2.bbox('all'))

root.bind('<Configure>', on_configure) 


def close_window():
    canvasF2.destroy()
    root.destroy()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_window)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!